# Recycle view adapter how i highlighted single item on click

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm using recycler view and I implement this functionality as per project requirement. But in my case item is highlighted but not unhighlighted again.
I was confused where I click the item for creating the clicking functionality, and how to unhighlighted the item. Please suggest me the right way to solve the code

```
public class LoadVehicleTypeAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LoadVehicleTypeAdapter.CarTypesHolder> {

    private List<TaxiTypeResponse.Message> CarTypesModelsList;
    private Context mContext;
    VehicleTypeView vehicleTypeView;
    setOnitemclick listener;
    private SparseBooleanArray selectedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();
    int I=-1;
    public class CarTypesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public CustomTextView mCarType;
        public CircleImageView mCarTypeImage;
        LinearLayout llRoot;
        CardView cardView;
        private SparseBooleanArray selectedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();
        setOnitemclick listener;

        public CarTypesHolder(final View view) {
            super(view);
            mCarType = (CustomTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.frag_cartypes_inflated_name);
            mCarTypeImage = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.frag_cartype_inflated_frameImage);
            llRoot = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.root1);
            cardView=(CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardf);


        }

        public void setOnItemClickListner(setOnitemclick listener12) {
            listener=listener12;
        }

    }
    public void setOnItemClickListner(setOnitemclick listener12) {
        listener=listener12;
    }


    public LoadVehicleTypeAdapter(Context context, List<TaxiTypeResponse.Message> CarTypesModelsList, VehicleTypeView vehicleTypeView) {
        this.CarTypesModelsList = CarTypesModelsList;
        mContext = context;
        this.vehicleTypeView = vehicleTypeView;
    }


    @Override
    public CarTypesHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView;
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.frag_cartype_inflated_view, parent, false);
        return new CarTypesHolder(itemView);
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final CarTypesHolder holder, final int position) {

        TaxiTypeResponse.Message carTypesModel = CarTypesModelsList.get(position);
        I=CarTypesModelsList.get(position).getID();
         holder.mCarType.setText(carTypesModel.getName());
         holder.mCarTypeImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wait);
        int color = Color.parseColor(PreferenceHandler.readString(mContext,PreferenceHandler.SECONDRY_COLOR,"#006fb6"));
        holder.llRoot.setSelected(selectedItems.get(position, false));
        holder.mCarType.setTextColor(color);
        holder.setOnItemClickListner(listener);

        holder. llRoot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                I=position;
                holder.llRoot.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));
                holder.mCarType.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));


                notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });
        if (I==position)
        {

            holder.llRoot.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));
            holder.mCarType.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

        }
        else
        {
            holder.llRoot.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));
            holder.mCarType.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));

        }

       Picasso.with(mContext).load(carTypesModel.getImagePath()).into(holder.mCarTypeImage);

    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return CarTypesModelsList.get(position).getID();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return CarTypesModelsList.size();
    }

    public void setSelection(LinearLayout imageView,CustomTextView textView,boolean value,int position){
        if(value){

            imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));
            textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

        }else{
            System.out.println("11111111111111111000000111111111111");
            imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f3f3f3"));
            textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2196F3"));

         }
     }
     public interface  setOnitemclick{
        void ImageClick(int position, String Name,String Description,int id);
         void ImageClickfade(int position, String Name,String Description,int id);
     }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll use to update gradle

`maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }`

and update the code

```
public class LoadVehicleTypeAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LoadVehicleTypeAdapter.CarTypesHolder> {

private List<TaxiTypeResponse.Message> CarTypesModelsList;
private Context mContext;
VehicleTypeView vehicleTypeView;
int I=-1;
public class CarTypesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements  View.OnClickListener {
    public CustomTextView mCarType;
    public CircleImageView mCarTypeImage;
    LinearLayout llRoot;
    CardView cardView;
    setOnitemclick listener;
    public void setOnItemClickListner(setOnitemclick listener)
    {
        this.listener=listener;
    }

    public CarTypesHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        mCarType = (CustomTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.frag_cartypes_inflated_name);
        mCarTypeImage = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.frag_cartype_inflated_frameImage);
        llRoot = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.root1);
        cardView=(CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardf);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    listener.ImageClick(v,getAdapterPosition());
    }
}


public LoadVehicleTypeAdapter(Context context, List<TaxiTypeResponse.Message> CarTypesModelsList, VehicleTypeView vehicleTypeView) {
    this.CarTypesModelsList = CarTypesModelsList;
    mContext = context;
    this.vehicleTypeView = vehicleTypeView;
}


@Override
public CarTypesHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.frag_cartype_inflated_view, parent, false);
    return new CarTypesHolder(itemView);
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder( final  CarTypesHolder holder,  int position) {

    TaxiTypeResponse.Message carTypesModel = CarTypesModelsList.get(position);
     holder.mCarType.setText(carTypesModel.getName());
     holder.mCarTypeImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wait);
    int color = Color.parseColor(PreferenceHandler.readString(mContext,PreferenceHandler.SECONDRY_COLOR,"#006fb6"));
    holder.mCarType.setTextColor(color);
    holder.setOnItemClickListner(new setOnitemclick() {
        @Override
        public void ImageClick(View v,int position1) {
            I=position1;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            System.out.println("11100011111");
            holder.llRoot.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));
            holder.mCarType.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }
    });
    if (I==position)
    {
        System.out.println("11100011111....");
        holder.llRoot.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));
        holder.mCarType.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("11100011111----");
        holder.llRoot.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f3f3f3"));
        holder.mCarType.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2196F3"));

    }

   Picasso.with(mContext).load(carTypesModel.getImagePath()).into(holder.mCarTypeImage);

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return CarTypesModelsList.get(position).getID();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return CarTypesModelsList.size();
}

public void setSelection(LinearLayout imageView,CustomTextView textView,boolean value,int position){
    if(value){

        imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));
        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

    }else{
        System.out.println("11111111111111111000000111111111111");
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f3f3f3"));
        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2196F3"));

     }
 }
 public interface  setOnitemclick{
    void ImageClick(View view,int position);
 }
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

}